# Is this doable in a DataGrid control?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid

I'm in the process of planning a software (for private use) .. The main feature in the application is a data grid.

I will have a button that adds a new row to the data grid. I'm thinking of adding the row directly in the data grid rather than having another window to add the data. In other words, when I click "NEW", a new row will appear directly in the data grid that is editable until I click save. During the editing, there can be drop-downs in some fields. Can this be achieved using C# with either Windows Forms or WPF? If possible, code to demonstrate would be useful.

Comment: Yes it can be done. You need to try something however.

Comment: @MBen : Can you provide a piece of code to demonstrate?

Comment: @sikas are obliged to use a button for adding rows ? cause a datagrid adds a blanc row automatically

Comment: @HichemC : I want, when the button is pressed, a new row is added with some drop-down menus

Comment: @sikas sorry I couldn't get : "with some drop-down menus".Where can they be shown ?

Comment: Kind a drop-down menu in row cells to make choices..Datagrid has a column of type ComboBox. is that what you're looking for ? waiting for you answer so i can maybe add some code to my answer.

Comment: @sikas Are you using WPF of WinForms? Anyway I used 5 min to generate a WinForms example for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brief exemple using data binding :*

in XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="0,0,417,277" Click="Button_Click">ADD</Button>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable}" Margin="0,40,0,21" CanUserAddRows="False">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

in Code behind .cs :

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            MyDataTable = new DataTable();
            MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Column1");
            MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Column2");

        }
        private DataTable _MyDataTable;
        public DataTable MyDataTable
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyDataTable;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyDataTable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDataTable");
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow row = MyDataTable.NewRow();

            MyDataTable.Rows.Add(row);


        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example that should give you a springboard to implement this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Add New Item" x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind: (Not a fan of code behind, but for a quick and dirty example)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> guys { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        guys = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
        guys.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "First Guy", Age = 21, FavoriteColor = "Blue" });
        guys.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "Second Guy", Age = 22, FavoriteColor = "Red" });
        guys.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "Third Guy", Age = 23, FavoriteColor = "Yellow" });
        guys.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "Fourth Guy", Age = 24, FavoriteColor = "Green" });
        myGrid.ItemsSource = guys;
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public String FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    }

    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        guys.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "[New Guy]", Age = 0, FavoriteColor = "[Color]" });
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code for Windows Forms. You have to create a form, add a DataGridView component into it (with some columns of your choice). Add also btnNew and btnSave buttons and bind to corresponding click -events.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Hide row headers
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    }

    // Add new row to grid
    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Insert new row as the first row
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new DataGridViewRow());

        // Set the current cell to the first cell in the newly added row
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];

        // Begin edit so that the focus goes straight to the new row
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }

    // "Save" (make the rows non editable)
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {                
            // Set readonly so the user won't be able to edit these rows anymore
            row.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```